# Is there a way to pull or search for data from other sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, search

We use Google Sheets for tech commission sheets (track jobs and hours). Right now we have 2 years (2017&2018) in 1 set of sheets, 1 sheet for each month (jan 17, feb 17, etc). So instead of adding more sheets, I would like to just create a new set of sheets for 2019 but I need to be able to pull/search for data from the 2017/2018 sheets to ensure a tech doesn't accidentally pay themselves for a job twice.

Is this possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1GOvESQ3lPEZbHeU4pPNGWDBznqqLRh3ly7Xt3r-q2vY",B1&"!"&B2), B3, 1)
```

[image: c]